# How to use a customed permission in Android framework?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an android system service(not app) which is used by android applications.  I want to add a customed permission to this system service, then an application has to have this permission to access my service.
Now, I've added a permision in /frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml, say com.test.testpermission.
But what else should I do to use this permission in the system service?

Comment: Take CameraService for exmaple, I don't know how android framework associate the permission in AndroidManifest.xml with the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the service code you need to add permission check into all public API's exposed by the service. To check the permissions you can use this approach:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("com.test.testpermission") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, the client app have to have your permission listed in its manifest.

I never tried it by myself but I can see it is used by TelephonyRegistry service for example.

For native code I can see this in camera service:

```
if (!checkCallingPermission(
                    String16("android.permission.CAMERA"))) {
                const int uid = getCallingUid();
                LOGE("Permission Denial: "
                     "can't use the camera pid=%d, uid=%d", pid, uid);
                return PERMISSION_DENIED;
            }
```

Comment: I checked android source code and it indeed checks permission in service code as you said. I will try this in my service. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: sorry, I forgot mention that my service is writen with C++ like cameraservice. And the method above is adopted by some service in java. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I found something in cameraservice. Maybe I can use  checkCallingPermission(String16("com.test.testpermission")) instead.

Comment: right =) that's what I was going to tell. But you have found it already.